# I want to read and add integers from a file line by line in C. File also has alphabets and special characters

Tags: c++, c

The file is like this:

```
A(20,50)(40,50)(45,67)

B(20,60)(40,50)(45,67)

C(30,70)(40,50)(45,67)
```

I have written the following code:

```
{
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("test2file", "r");
char symb;
int i,j=0;

if (myFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}

while ((symb=getc(myFile))!=EOF)
{
  fscanf (myFile, "%d",&i);
  printf ("%d ", i);
  j=j+i;
  printf("\nsum:%d",j);
}

return 0;
```

}

Output is:

```
415888

sum:41588820

sum:41590850
```

and so on.

Comment: You might want to expand upon how your code is not working as you expect, what errors you see and what you have done to debug.

Comment: You can test the return value of `fscanf(myFile, "%d",&i)`: it is 1 if and only if an integer has been successfully read.

Comment: You have not checked the return value from `fscanf`. So when it fails to read the first number, because it reads a `'('` character, `i` is still an *uninitialised variable* and so garbage is printed. The garbage value is `415888` foloowed by the correct `20` and `50` but the example output was not produced by the code you have posted, which separates each number with a `space`.

Comment: Is sum  each row?

Comment: Mybad about the "space" part of my last comment, too late to edit.

Comment: I'm confused.  You want an answer in C (per your title) but you tagged question as C++.  They are different languages.  For example, C++ has the `std::string` type and C doesn't.  Please remove the appropriate tag.

Comment: Is the requirement to add all  the numbers or to determine the area using the three points?  The data looks like each row determines a plane or triangle (or could be 3 collinear points in a line).

Comment: [like this ?](http://ideone.com/97BAZ8)

Comment: @Yusra.S feel free for any queries

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes, these numbers are coordinates of vertices of triangle, I actually need to calculate the length of each edge. Before trying that I simply wanted to check whether my code is reading the numbers correctly but it is not reading the numbers as integers rather numbers are read as string.

Comment: I recommend creating a `point` class that has an overloaded `operator>>` to read in the X and Y values.  This would simplify your program especially the reading of the data.  You could also implement a function that subtracts two `point` instances.  This gets more difficult in the C language; because you can't overload operators in the C language.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I removed all special character symbol  ',' '(' ')' from the file. Although, now I am not getting any garbage value in the output, but the numbers are not read as integers. The output I am getting now is:0 sum:050 sum:5040 and so on.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: thank you for help, I have implemented the function for calculating length of the edges. I am not able to proceed further as my numbers are not read as integers. I am not able to perform any mathematical operation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question as C++, I'll provide a C++ answer.

Use `std::string` and `std::getline` to read in a row of text, then use functions in `std::string` to parse and isolate the fields.

Example:

```
std::ifstream input("test2file");
if (!input)
{
  std::cerr << "Error opening data file\n";
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
std::string text_row;
std::string::size_type number_position = 0;
int sum = 0;
while (std::getline(input, text_row)
{
  static const char digits[] = "0123456789";
  std::string::size_type number_position = text_row.find_first_of(digits, number_position);
  std::string::size_type number_end_position = 
       text_row.find_first_not_of(digits, number_position);
  std::string number_text = text_row.substr(number_position,
                                            number_end_position - number_position);
  std::istringstream number_stream(number_text);
  int number = 0;
  number_stream >> number;
  sum += number;
  number_position = number_end_position + 1;
}
```